# Systems and signals - integration with dirac's function and step function

Tags: signal, system

I'm taking the introductory course to systems and signals and the mathematics of integration using the step function and Dirac's function

[image: integral 1]

and

[image: problem 2]

For the first integral, I just don't know how to deal with u(t-4), the step function.

The other two questions i don't even know how to start. Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Though it has to do with signals, this would be a better fit for math.SE in my opinion.

Comment: "For the first integral, I just don't know how to deal with u(t-4), the step function." Hint: Think of the behaviour of u(t-4) when t<4.

Comment: I actually tried this on math.SE and they put my question on hold, so I guessed i should try ee.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u(t-4) means that the integral is equal to zero till you reach 4, so compute the integral from 4 to infinity.
the last question, it's about convolution of h(t) and x(t). for x(t), t<0 always x(t)=0, t=0 x(t) = 1 and t>0 x(t)= -1. draw x(t), you have h(t). convolve them.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you want to calculate:

1. The first integral,
   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}tu(t-4)\,dt$$
2. This one:
   $$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-(t-\sigma)\mathrm{e}^{-(t-\sigma)}u(t-\sigma)\sigma^2\mathrm{e}^{-\sigma}\sin(\sigma)u(\sigma)\,d\sigma\qquad t\geq0$$
3. And the last one:
   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t-\tau)x(\tau)\,d\tau$$
   with
   $$x(t)=\delta(t)\mathrm{e}^{-t}-u(t)$$

Let's go step by step.

---

**FIRST:**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}tu(t-4)\,dt$$

Note that the step function u(t-4) means that, before t=4, all the integrand is being multiplied by 0, so:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}tu(t-4)\,dt=\int_{4}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}t\,dt$$

Now, notice that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}=-2t\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}$$
so
$$\int_{4}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}t\,dt=-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}\Bigg|_4^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-16}$$

---

**SECOND:**

Notice that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
y(t)&=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-(t-\sigma)\mathrm{e}^{-(t-\sigma)}u(t-\sigma)\sigma^2\mathrm{e}^{-\sigma}\sin(\sigma)u(\sigma)\,d\sigma\\
&=&\int_{0}^{t}-(t-\sigma)\mathrm{e}^{-(t-\sigma)}\sigma^2\mathrm{e}^{-\sigma}\sin(\sigma)\,d\sigma\\
&=&\mathrm{e}^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}-(t-\sigma)\sigma^2\sin(\sigma)\,d\sigma\\
&=&-t\mathrm{e}^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2\sin(\sigma)\,d\sigma+\mathrm{e}^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^3\sin(\sigma)\,d\sigma\\
\end{array}$$

Both integrals can be solved using integration by parts. The first one, let u=sigma^2 and dv=sin(sigma), so
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2\sin(\sigma)\,d\sigma&=&-\sigma^2\cos(\sigma)\Bigg|_0^t+\int_0^t\sigma\cos(\sigma)\,d\sigma\\
&=&-\sigma^2\cos(\sigma)\Bigg|_0^t+2\sigma\sin(\sigma)\Bigg|_0^t-2\sigma\Bigg|_0^t\\
&=&-t^2\cos(t)+2t\sin(t)-2t
\end{array}$$
You even can use this result to calculate the second integral (I'll leave it to you).

---

**THIRD: just hints**

The important thing here is trying to describe h in terms of step functions. You can do it as:
$$h(t)=u(t-1)+u(t-2)-u(t-3)-u(t-4)$$
or, if you want, as rect (boxcar) functions:
$$h(t)=\sqcap(t-\frac{3}{2})+2\sqcap(t-\frac{5}{2})+\sqcap(t-\frac{7}{2})$$

If we take the first expression, then
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
h(t-\tau)x(\tau)&=&\bigg(u(t-\tau-1)+u(t-\tau-2)-u(t-\tau-3)-u(t-\tau-4)\bigg)\\
&&\cdot\bigg(\delta(\tau)\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}-u(\tau)\bigg)\\
&=&\delta(\tau)\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}u(t-\tau-1)-u(\tau)u(t-\tau-1)\\
&&+\delta(\tau)\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}u(t-\tau-2)-u(\tau)u(t-\tau-2)\\
&&-\delta(\tau)\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}u(t-\tau-3)+u(\tau)u(t-\tau-3)\\
&&-\delta(\tau)\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}u(t-\tau-4)+u(\tau)u(t-\tau-4)
\end{array}$$

HINT: Note that, if t0 is in the integration interval (a,b), the Dirac delta satisfies
$$\int_a^b\delta(t-t_0)f(t)\,dt=f(t_0)$$
Then, note that for the Dirac delta in x(t), t_0=0.